# Create HashSet on the basis of Class Attribute

Tags: java, android, hashset

> I have to create `HashMap<Integer,List<StoreItem>>` using an ArrayList . I want HashSet on the basis of store Number as we do in Ios like `myArrayList.distinctUnionOfObjects.storeNumber`

```
public static List<StoreItem> getStoreList(){
        List<StoreItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

        items.add(new StoreItem(503,"Brufeen",10));
        items.add(new StoreItem(503,"hydriline",8));
        items.add(new StoreItem(503,"Brufeen",10));
        items.add(new StoreItem(503,"capsule",2));
        items.add(new StoreItem(503,"Disprin",6));


        items.add(new StoreItem(504,"Pixlar",9));
        items.add(new StoreItem(504,"Luprin",17));
        items.add(new StoreItem(504,"BOOM BOOM",14));
        items.add(new StoreItem(504,"Glucophage",22));
        items.add(new StoreItem(504,"Panadol",16));


        items.add(new StoreItem(549,"Pixlar",9));
        items.add(new StoreItem(549,"Luprin",17));
        items.add(new StoreItem(549,"BOOM BOOM",14));
        items.add(new StoreItem(549,"Glucophage",22));
        items.add(new StoreItem(549,"Panadol",16));

        return items;


    }

    public static HashMap<Integer,List<StoreItem>> getStoreHashMap(){
        List<StoreItem> oldStores = StoreFactory.getStoreList();

        Set<StoreItem> uniqueSet = new HashSet<StoreItem>(oldStores);

        HashMap<Integer,List<StoreItem>> dictionaryOfStore = new HashMap<>();

        for(StoreItem keyItem : uniqueSet )
        {
            List<StoreItem> storeInSection = new ArrayList<>();
            for(StoreItem oldItem : oldStores)
            {
                if(keyItem.getStoreNumber() == oldItem.getStoreNumber()){
                    storeInSection.add(oldItem);
                }
            }
            dictionaryOfStore.put(keyItem.getStoreNumber(),storeInSection);
        }

        return dictionaryOfStore;
    }
```

uniqueSet is returning 15 because it compare whole StoreItem object. I need a method which create HashSet on the basis of StoreItem.getStoreNumber()

where StoreItem

```
public class StoreItem {

    private int storeNumber;
    private String capsuleNames;
    private int quantity;

    public StoreItem(int storeNumber, String capsuleNames, int quantity) {
        this.storeNumber = storeNumber;
        this.capsuleNames = capsuleNames;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

or is there a way to override hashset Comparison.

And I know I can do it with check's in For Loop.

Comment: I’m thinking of two options: (1) Use a `TreeSet` and a custom comparator rather than a `HashSet` (2) If you insist on a `HashSet`, make it a `HashSet<MyList>` where `MyList` extends `ArrayList` with appropriate `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve this with a Comparator. You can change getStorehashMap() method like this:

```
public static HashMap<Integer, List<StoreItem>> getStoreHashMap() {
    List<StoreItem> oldStores = getStoreList();
    HashMap<Integer, List<StoreItem>> dictionaryOfStore = new HashMap<Integer, List<StoreItem>>();

    for (StoreItem keyItem : oldStores) {
        if(!dictionaryOfStore.containsKey(keyItem.getStoreNumber())) {
            dictionaryOfStore.put(keyItem.getStoreNumber(), new ArrayList<StoreItem>());
        }
        dictionaryOfStore.get(keyItem.getStoreNumber()).add(keyItem);
    }

    return dictionaryOfStore;
}
```

Comment: I filled it on the last line of the for loop.